# Home Backup for OSX and Windows

Tags: osx, backup, windows-10

Anyone who can suggest a good / tested solution for my scenario.

I have MacBook Pro 2015 with running both El Capitan and Windows 10 (Boot Camp).

I would like to be able to do Regular backups preferably wirelessly.  I understand that 1st backup will be large in size so I am fine doing that 1st one over the wire.  I am also open to do backups only over the wire if that is better than over the Wi-Fi.

I am looking for some good steps to set up such environment where I can backup both Windows and Mac side.

**UPDATE**
I'd like to backup to external drive or NAS.

Comment: Thanks.  I have removed the streaming part as you suggested.

Comment: OK, that looks much more understandable now. Time for comment cleanup then :) One more clarification: Do you need a GUI, or would command-line tools be acceptable too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that everything is accessible from the Mac side, **[Rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)** would be a good choice. It's a [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) tool that [already ships with MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html) and is also available for Windows (and Linux), and also has [some GUIs available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#rsync_applications). A good and easy GUI would be [LuckyBackup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuckyBackup) – again cross-platform and available for all mentioned OSes:

[image: LuckyBackup] [image: LuckyBackup]
<sup>*LuckyBackup* (source: [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luckybackup/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

*RSync* itself can work locally or via network, so it would meet your requirements for doing the initial backup via cable (e.g. USB disk) as well as doing it wirelessly (provided the disk/storage is available via TCP/IP). Being cross-platform, you could also run it on Windows (though that would need [some preparation in terms of installation and configuration](http://www.bmtsolutions.us/wiki/doku.php?id=contrib:luckybackup-win)).

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and see if it works for me.  It seem to have all I need.  Does it have automatic backup feature or I need to start it manually?  it would be nice to have automatic backups overnight which it probably has.  I'll also see if I can get few other recommendations and check them.  Much appreciated

Comment: I schedule my rsync backups via Cron – a feature which LuckyBackup obviously supports as well (see second screenshot: "Everyday Backups" wouldn't make much sense otherwise – plus the Sourceforge page explicitly mentions "Scheduling").

Comment: Always glad to help :) Enjoy!